# Скрыть невыбранные <options> из <select>

Tags: javascript

Есть две кнопки - каждая выбирает свой `option` из `select`. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на копку, все `option`, кроме выбранного, скрывались или становились неактивными.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('group')[0].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var elem = evt.target;
  if (elem.hasAttribute('data-select')) {
    document.getElementById('select').value = elem.getAttribute('data-select');

    var elem = document.getElementById('select');
    var event = new Event('change');
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label class="primary">
<input data-select="3" type="button">Кнопка 1</label>
  <label class="primary">
<input data-select="4" type="button">Кнопка 2</label>
</div>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Выбор пункта 1</option>
  <option value="2">Выбор пункта 2</option>
  <option value="3">Выбор пункта 3</option>
  <option value="4">Выбор пункта 4</option>
  <option value="5">Выбор пункта 5</option>
  <option value="6" checked>Выбор пункта 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:
В моём примере перебираются все тэги `option`, которые находятся внутри `select`. Если `option.value !== select.value`, то `option` становится неактивным, иначе - наоборот.

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName('group')[0].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var elem = evt.target;
    if (elem.hasAttribute('data-select')) {
      let select = document.getElementById('select');
      select.value = elem.getAttribute('data-select');
      
      let options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
      Array.from(options, (option, i) => options[i].disabled = (option.value !== select.value ? true : false));
      
      var elem = document.getElementById('select');
      var event = new Event('change');
      elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }, false);
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label class="primary">
<input data-select="3" type="button">Кнопка 1</label>
  <label class="primary">
<input data-select="4" type="button">Кнопка 2</label>
</div>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Выбор пункта 1</option>
  <option value="2">Выбор пункта 2</option>
  <option value="3">Выбор пункта 3</option>
  <option value="4">Выбор пункта 4</option>
  <option value="5">Выбор пункта 5</option>
  <option value="6" checked>Выбор пункта 6</option>
</select>
```

Аналогичный пример, но со скрытием не выбранных `option`:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('group')[0].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var elem = evt.target;
  if (elem.hasAttribute('data-select')) {
    let select = document.getElementById('select');
    select.value = elem.getAttribute('data-select');

    let options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    Array.from(options, (option, i) => options[i].style.display = (option.value !== select.value ? 'none' : 'block'));

    var elem = document.getElementById('select');
    var event = new Event('change');
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label class="primary">
<input data-select="3" type="button">Кнопка 1</label>
  <label class="primary">
<input data-select="4" type="button">Кнопка 2</label>
</div>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Выбор пункта 1</option>
  <option value="2">Выбор пункта 2</option>
  <option value="3">Выбор пункта 3</option>
  <option value="4">Выбор пункта 4</option>
  <option value="5">Выбор пункта 5</option>
  <option value="6" checked>Выбор пункта 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Извиняюсь, а можно сделать к примеру: кнопку 1 оставляем функционал такой же (с блокировкой остальных), а кнопка 2 чтобы выбирала option 4 но не блокировала остальные?

Comment: Добавьте проверку - если`select.value === "4"`, то не блокируем.